# MySQL query won't return expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following set of data:
[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T2DH.png)

Where the schema is defined as follows:

```
Episodes (season (PK), num (PK), title, director, viewers)
Characters (name (PK), house)
Appearances (name (PK), season (PK), num (PK))
FK: Appearances.name -> Characters.name
FK: Appearances.season -> Episodes.season
```

I am trying to build the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Episodes.title
FROM Episodes, Appearances
WHERE Episodes.director = 'Van Patten' AND Appearances.name != 'Robb';
```

However, the result I get back is `Winter is Coming` and `The Kingsroad` When I am only expecting to get `The Kingsroad`

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: This is what I have just tried by doing a join, however it still is giving me the same result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Episodes.title
FROM Episodes, Appearances, Characters
WHERE 
Episodes.season = Appearances.season AND
Episodes.num = Appearances.num AND
Characters.name = Appearances.name AND
Episodes.director = 'Van Patten' AND 
Characters.name != 'Robb';
```

I have supplied the creation of the tables, and the insertions below.

```
CREATE TABLE Episodes (
    season INT,
    num INT,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    director VARCHAR(50),
    viewers DECIMAL(2, 1),
    PRIMARY KEY (season, num)
);

CREATE TABLE Characters (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    house VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);

CREATE TABLE Appearances (
    name VARCHAR(50),
    season INT,
    num INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, season, num),
    FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES Characters(name),
    FOREIGN KEY (season) REFERENCES Episodes(season)
);


# Episodes Table Inserts

INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (1, 1, 'Winter is Coming', 'Van Patten', 2.2);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (1, 2, 'The Kingsroad', 'Van Patten', 2.2);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (1, 3, 'Lord Snow', 'Kirk', 2.4);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (1, 4, 'Cripples, Bastards', 'Kirk', 2.4);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (1, 5, 'The Wolf & the Lion', 'Kirk', 2.6);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (2, 1, 'The North Remembers', 'Taylor', 3.9);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (2, 2, 'The Night Lands', 'Taylor', 3.8);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (2, 3, 'What is Dead May Never Die', 'Sakharov', 3.8);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (2, 4, 'Garden of Bones', 'Petrarca', 3.7);
INSERT INTO Episodes VALUES (2, 5, 'The Ghost of Harrenhal', 'Petrarca', 3.9);


# Characters Table Inserts

INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Eddard', 'Stark');
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Robb', 'Stark');
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('John Snow', 'Stark');
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Ygritte', NULL);
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Tyrion', 'Lannister');
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Cercei', 'Lannister');
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Jaime', 'Lannister');
INSERT INTO Characters VALUES ('Daenerys', 'Targaryen');


# Appearances Table Inserts

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Eddard', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Eddard', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Eddard', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Eddard', 1, 4);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Eddard', 1, 5);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Robb', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Robb', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Robb', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Robb', 2, 3);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('John Snow', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('John Snow', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('John Snow', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('John Snow', 2, 4);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('John Snow', 2, 5);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Ygritte', 2, 4);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Ygritte', 2, 5);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Tyrion', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Tyrion', 1, 2);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Cercei', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Cercei', 2, 3);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Jaime', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Jaime', 2, 4);

INSERT INTO Appearances VALUES ('Daenerys', 1, 1);
```

Comment: You’re not joining the tables in any way so it’ll create a combination of the rows that match and return that. You’ll need to join them together to get the results you want.

Comment: Oh I see. So I need to do something like `Appearances.name = Characters.name` (Just as an example) ?

Comment: Try your query without the DISTINCT and adding all of the fields you are using for conditions. It will give you a better idea of what the problem is. For example: SELECT
  Episodes.title,
  Episodes.director,
  Appearances.name
FROM
  Episodes,
  Appearances
WHERE
  Episodes.director = 'Van Patten'
AND
  Appearances.name != 'Robb'
AND
  Appearances.season = Episodes.season
AND
  Appearances.num = Episodes.num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each episode there are multiple characters appearing.
So by setting the condition:

```
Characters.name != 'Robb'
```

this does not remove the episode from the returned rows because there are rows remaining for this episode with the other characters.
 
You must join (by using proper joins and aliases) the tables, `group by title` and set the 1st condition in the `WHERE` clause and the 2nd in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT e.title
FROM Episodes e
INNER JOIN Appearances a ON a.season = e.season AND a.num = e.num
INNER JOIN Characters c ON c.name = a.name
WHERE e.director = 'Van Patten'
GROUP BY e.title
HAVING SUM(c.name = 'Robb') = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3yUwnz1zEiitjc8TWtgVXj/1).
Results:

```
| title         |
| ------------- |
| The Kingsroad |
```